# How do I list who needs special dietary requirements?

Tags: excel

I hope this isn't too simple of a question, but I am creating an Excel spreadsheet for an upcoming meal listing participants in column A, and special dietary requirements in column F.

Is it possible to create a formula that will allow me to have a cell that lists the people with special dietary requirements?

I.E. If I input in column F that `Persons 1, 4, 6, 18, 34, 48, 56, etc....` can I have a cell that creates a list of names of people with special dietary requirements? (+ a cell that totals the number of these would be great too)

Answer (score 1):

The formula to display the total number of persons with special dietary requirements is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(F2:F999)>0))
```

The above assumes cell F1 has a column title in it.

To report a list of those people in one cell is not so easy...

Let's assume that you placed the above formula into cell Z1 and so Z1 currently displays the total. The following formula will list the names, but it uses Z1. So if you placed the above formula somewhere else (which is likely) then you must change the Z1's in this formula:

```
=IF(Z1>0,INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),1)),"")    &    IF(Z1>1,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),2)),"")    &    IF(Z1>2,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),3)),"")   &    IF(Z1>3,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),4)),"")   &    IF(Z1>4,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),5)),"")   &    IF(Z1>5,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),6)),"")   &    IF(Z1>6,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),7)),"")   &    IF(Z1>7,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),8)),"")   &    IF(Z1>8,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),9)),"")   &    IF(Z1>9,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),10)),"")
```

It is necessarily very long so copy and paste it into one cell, perhaps Z2.

Now confirm the formula.

> This 2nd formula is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It is currently setup to report a maximum of TEN persons with special dietary requirements separated by comma in the cell you enter it.

It can easily be extended. Note the large gaps throughout the formula. You can see ten discreet formulas stitched together with the ampersand (&) concatenation operator. To extend it to accommodate more than ten persons with special dietary requirements, simply copy the last segment and edit two numerals in the new segment.

I have reformatted the 2nd formula below. With this format it is much easier to see the pattern:

```
=IF(Z1>0,     INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),1)),"")&
 IF(Z1>1,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),2)),"")&
 IF(Z1>2,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),3)),"")&
 IF(Z1>3,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),4)),"")&
 IF(Z1>4,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),5)),"")&
 IF(Z1>5,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),6)),"")&
 IF(Z1>6,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),7)),"")&
 IF(Z1>7,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),8)),"")&
 IF(Z1>8,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),9)),"")&
 IF(Z1>9,", "&INDEX(REPT(A2:A999,LEN(F2:F999)>0),LARGE(ROW(1:998)*(LEN(F2:F999)>0),10)),"")
```

Excel is not good at returning a list like this into one cell and that is why the formula is so long.

Comment: Thanks Excel Hero for that, it worked to Sum the total number, but it would be great to have a list of their names too!

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data like:

[image]

To list the people that require, say low salt, set up an *AutoFilter* on column **F**:

[image]

To count the number of low salt people, use:

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,"low salt")
```

This does not get you the names in a single cell, but it does get the names.